# Uniformly continuous function induces another uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f: X \to X$ is uniformly continous.

Define $\varphi: X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(x) = d[x,f(x)],\forall x \in X$. Does $\varphi$ need to be uniformly continuous?

I know that $\varphi$ is continous, but I'm not sure if it's uniformly continous.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: using triangular inequality twice $$d(x,f(x))\le d(x,y)+d(y,f(x))\le d(x,y)+d(y,f(y))+d(f(y),f(x))$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: From there we get $|\varphi(x) -\varphi(y)| \le d(x,y)+ d(f(x),f(y))$ and how we can continue?

Comment: Now you can use uniform continuity of $f$. Whatever $x,y\in X$, $$d(x,y)<\delta\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
|\varphi(x) - \varphi(y)| = |d(x,f(x)) - d(y,f(y))|
 =|d(x,f(x)) - d(y,f(x)) + d(y, f(x)) - d(y, f(y))|
 \le |d(x, f(x)) - d(y,f(x))| + |d(y, f(x)) - d(y, f(y))|.
$$

The reverse triangle inequality tells you that $|d(y, f(x)) - d(x,f(x))| \le d(x,y)$, and also that $|d(y, f(x)) - d(y, f(y))| \le d(f(x), f(y))$. So you end up with
$$
|\varphi(x) - \varphi(y)| \le d(x,y) + d(f(x),f(y)).
$$

So the uniform continuity of $f$ now implies uniform continuity of $\varphi$.